# SQL select problems

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table named Find, and I want to return the number of SessionID with names having both "/topic" and "/detail". Therefore, it should return 1 in my case since only SessionID=1 has both "/topic" and "/detail" in the column "name". 
[image]

i tried to use the following code but i guess i messed up GROUP BY again.

Thx!

```
         Select count( distinct `SessionID`)
         from Find 
         where `name` like "/detail%" 
           and `name` like "/topic%"  
         group by `SessionID`, `date` 
         order by `date`;
```

I also have another column named "date" which did not show up in my screenshot. The column date tells which date the SessionID is collected. So i thought I could group by SessionID for my purpose mentioned above, and then group by date. Therefore at the end, I will know the number of SessionID meeting requirement by each day.

Comment: 1. Is the name of your table above `table` in the DB? 2. Look at your `name` filter criteria in the `WHERE` clause; you've got a typo. You're not checking for "/topic". 3. why do you need to both group by and order by date? Are you certain the group by on date is needed?

Comment: What does the date column represent? Is it related to the sessionId?

Comment: yes, it is related to sessionID, it tells the date of the SessionID. say "april1" for sessionID=1,2    and "april2" for sessionID=3

Comment: @JonathonOgden   1. the table name should be Find, sorry about the typo. 2. i modified my code for checking for "/topic", and it is still not working. 3. technically, i want to know the number of sessionIDs meeting requirements for each day. thats why i want to group by ID, and then by date. probably i did it wrong again. but thx for the reply!

Comment: You should first find the sessions with both "topic" and "detail", then count them. If you want to just count the sessions, you don't need the date and your query should be something like this:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT F1.SessionID FROM Find F1, Find F2 WHERE F1.SessionId=F2.SessionId AND F1.name='detail' AND F2.name='topic')

If you want to count the sessions per day, then your query should be something like this:

SELECT date, COUNT(\*) FROM 
(SELECT F1.SessionID, F1.date FROM Find F1, Find F2 WHERE F1.SessionId=F2.SessionId AND F1.name='detail' AND F2.name='topic')
GROUP BY date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your query in 2 steps. First, you need to find out the sessions containing both `/details%` and `/topic%`. Then you can count them.

**Pivot rows for name lookup**

```
SELECT
    SessionID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name LIKE "/detail%" THEN 1 END) AS hasDetail,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name LIKE "/topic%"  THEN 1 END) AS hasTopic
FROM Find
GROUP BY SessionID
```

The result of the sub-query is :

```
SessionID  hasDetail  hasTopic
---------  ---------  --------
1          1          1
2                     1
3          1
```

**Count the result**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SessionID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "/detail%" THEN 1 END) AS hasDetail,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "/topic%"  THEN 1 END) AS hasTopic
    FROM Find
    GROUP BY SessionID
) AS A
WHERE A.hasDetail = 1 AND A.hasTopic = 1;
```

This query is written for MySQL database, please let me know if you need other SQL statement, such as T-SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: m using mysql workbench right now, i tested ur code and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You were close you just needed to include date and the count as different columns.  Like this:

```
     Select `SessionID`, `date`, count(*) as number
     from Find 
     where `name` like "/detail%" 
       or `name` like "/topic%"  
     group by `SessionID`, `date` 
     order by `date`;
```

Comment: I'm surprised. this won't work as the name column is not BOTH "/detail" and "/topic" on the same row, but across multiple rows.

Comment: @DRapp sorry it should be `or` not `and` I fixed it.